# Error when checking input: expected dense_28_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3084, 32, 32)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make a prediction with my model where shape of the array is **(3084, 32, 32)**. 
Getting **value Error** [here is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdyn8.png)

Here is my model

```
model.add(Dense(1028, input_shape = (3084,), activation = "sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(514, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))
```

summary

```
Model: "sequential_21"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_57 (Dense)             (None, 1028)              3171380   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_58 (Dense)             (None, 514)               528906    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_59 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 2060      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,702,346
Trainable params: 3,702,346
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

trying to fit using

```
opt = SGD(lr = 0.01)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
H = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data = (test_X, test_Y), epochs = 75, batch_size = 32)
```

Comment: Why is your input shape 3084 but passing 32,32 data?

Comment: As far as I understand i'm passing 3084  which is number of image to train. 32,32 is image size.

Comment: here is my full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eX9HGw6hdqFGvFlZlx4pewqfTnq4otJF?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the input shape correctly, the following model should work.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1028, input_shape = (32,32), activation = "sigmoid"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(514, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))

model.summary()
```

Comment: @HRShuvo, don't hesitate to accept/upvote when an answer helps :)